# HTTPS certificates on a Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, https, ssl-certificate

I'm connecting to an ASP.NET web service from a personal blackberry device (No IT policy). The connection is over HTTPS, so the user needs to explicitly trust this certificate and add it to their keystore to proceed. Since the app is targeted towards a (mostly) non technical user base, I don't think this is a good idea.

Is it possible to trust a certificate through code?

Thanks, 
Teja

Comment: Check in your device, there is a list of already trusted certificate, you should use one of them on your web site.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think I can get a certificate from a trusted authority like verisign, I need to use the one that is currently on the server, so I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put ;trustAll to the end of your connection URL.

Comment: This is timing out my connection somehow. I have a time out at the end of the URL and it works fine..